# How do I install node.js version 14 in ubuntu 18. Version?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-install, ubuntu-18.04, react-dom

[image][image]I want to learn and do work on react.

I have install and uninstall every package of node.js, npm so many times. But, everytime I found an error.

- Error with npm and many more error.

Every time I download and install node version 14.x.
But after that I check the version of node js it gives version 10.15.x.

I have download node, npm, react, react-dom, curl, webpack, babel and all the package for using react.

So, many times I do install and uninstall these packages and trying to get solutions from GitHub, YouTube, Google, stack overflow, geeks.

But, that problem is now solved. But, Now the second problem is coming. React localhost is running on the terminal and React page is also being open in the browser.

But if I am doing any changes in the App.js file that is not updating in the browser.And then when I run the same command code on VS Code terminal, then NPM is not starting and the same problem is coming up again.

How long have I been doing solve this problem? Don't know where and what the problem is.

Please, if anyone can help me in this then it will be very great full for me.

Answer (score 1):

Give https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm a try.

To install the desired node version `nvm install 14.0`

To use it (load it as the current version in a terminal session)

```
nvm use 14.0
```

You can set the default version you would like with.

```
nvm alias default 14.0
```

This will persist the version across your system.

14.0 can be changed to whatever version you would like.

Comment: Node JS version 14 is installed but the another error is coming again and again. Please have a look and please let me know if you know the solution. I am attaching an image in my question. Please have a look on the problem.

Comment: More information is required. However, if you haven't deleted the node_modules folder in between version switches it would be good to do. Delete `node_modules` and run `npm install`.

Comment: I have done this things already. After this it shows an another error. Node_modules found and npm not install and then same error is coming again. 

Comment: Did you attempt the steps provided by react-scripts?

Comment: Yes, I do everything step by step. But the same error is coming again and again. I don't get any solution yet.